# Не получается сгенерировать вид страницы(404 ошибка)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Здравствуйте, делаю свой первый проект по асп.нету в целях обучения. Но почему-то не могу сгенерировать страницу, на которой должна отобразиться страница с изображениями с бд, которая подвязана на айпи с таблицы Юзерс (стандартная таблица asp.net.identity).
Вот, собственно, здесь принимаю изображение с потока и добавляю в бд, после чего передаю айди пользователя:

```
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && uploadImage!=null)
        {
            byte[] imageData = null;

            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
            {
                imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
            }
            ApplicationUser au = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            Picture pic = new Picture();
            pic.Image = imageData;
            au.Pictures.Add(pic);

            db.Users.Add(au);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Response.Write("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " + validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("UserDetails", new { id = User.Identity.GetUserId() });
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Принимаю айди пользователя и отправляю объект в вид

```
 ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult UserDetails(int? id)
    {
        if (id==null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = db.Users.Include(t => t.Pictures).FirstOrDefault(t => int.Parse(t.Id) == id);
        if (applicationUser == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```

и сам вид

```html
@model IEnumerable<Aut.Models.ApplicationUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserDetails";
}

<h2>UserDetails</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", "Personal")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
    </tr>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    foreach (var picture in item.Pictures)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Raw("<img style='width:80px; height:60px;' src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"
                                + Convert.ToBase64String(picture.Image) + "\" />")
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}

</table>
```

Выдает 404 ошибку, но айпи принимает и передает, не понимаю, почему тогда не отображает. Правда перед этим выдавало эксепшн на ' db.SaveChanges();', но после вставки трай кэтч перестало почему-то. Спасибо заранее за помощь, буду благодарен.
[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

После вставки try/catch ты ему говоришь: "Друг, попробуй вставить, если не получится, то сделай тогда так". Если он тебя раньше ругал за SaveChanges, то видимо он не мог их сделать и не мог сохранить в базу. В блоке try он также пробует сохранить в базе, у него снова не получается, но теперь он не падает, а честно идет в блок catch. Итого имеем - сущность в базе не сохранена, записи с такими id нет, получаем 404.
И сдается мне saveChanges не работает потому что ты не обновляешь запись в базе, а добавляешь новую(делаешь Add), а запись с такими ID уже там есть, поэтому ошибка.
Чтоб точно быть уверенным, посмотри что у тебя там в базе творится.

Comment: убрал трай кэтч вставку и изменил на `ApplicationUser au = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                Picture pic = new Picture();
                pic.Image = imageData;
                au.Pictures.Add(pic);

                db.Entry(au).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: всеровно на 404 перебрасывает, но таблица Pictures пустая и правда где то в бд проблема, но почему 404 и что не так с бд =(

Answer (score 0):

помоему я понял в чем проблема, у asp.net identity id строкового типа, а у меня связочный столбец к в Pictures int

Comment: да, так и было.